# How to conditionally display HTML with EJS Template?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I tried following condition that's works fine,

```
<% if (user) { %>
  <h1> Success </h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1> Failure </h1>
 <% } %>
```

but I want to check the condition like below,

```
<% if (user.verified == true ) { %>
  <h1> Success </h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1> Failure </h1>
 <% } %>
```

Its not working, showing error.
Please anyone help me to fix the issue.

Comment: It should work, if `user.verified` is `true` boolean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check user is undefined or not. So the code should be:

```
<% if (user && user.verified == true) { %>
  <h1> Success </h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1> Failure </h1>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got a solution !!

```
<% if(typeof (user) != "undefined"){ %>
        <h1>User Exists</h1>
<% } %>
```

**Mind that undefined is placed inside " " (quotes).**

*Just FYI* :

> Undefined, null, "" (empty string) are  considered as a false in
>   Javascript but still here I was getting error due to undefined in ejs
>   file.

*Hope that helps !*